# how to use MCRYPT_MODE_CTR on php 5.4+

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption

I need to use MCRYPT_MODE_CTR with DES algorithm but I couldn't find it, 
i don't know why its maybe PHP remove it, so what should I use instead of it?

```
MCRYPT_MODE_CTR
```

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).

Comment: @zaph , i've checked both , but i didn't find what i need, i know the encryption will be weak but what i need to implement is DES with CTR mode that's all., could u tell me if any method on php could support this implementation, please?

Comment: Yeah to weak encryption, the attacker love it! But remember the same counter key combination should never be refused.

Comment: @zaph, yes i won't use it on an online website, but until now i searched everywhere and i didnt find any implementation of CTR mode with DES on php , so do u have any source that i can review it, please ?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenSSL? Do\n't be fooled by the name.

Comment: @zaph "OpenSSL does not implement CTR mode or OFB mode with 8-bit feedback, which is called 'ofb’ mode in Mcrypt. Mcrypt’s modes 'cfb’, 'ncfb’ and 'nofb’ correspond to OpenSSL’s 'cfb8’, 'cfb’ and 'ofb’ modes respectively."

Comment: Right, it seems they have done the right thing. You can implement CTR mode yourself rather easily. OTOH, this is a wakeup call that it is time to upgrade from DES to AES. See [Counter (CTR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) but that is not a good idea. Hopefully it is not user data that is being protected.

Comment: could u show/create to me any example of using DES with CTR mode on php please ? i really need this. thanks in advance.